# PDF/UA Embedded Fonts on OL/UL iText5 xmlworker

Tags: itext, xmlworker

I believe this issue will only affect people doing PDF/A or PDF/UA which requires font to be embedded in the document. I am using the XMLWorker with an xhtml document to produce the PDF.

If I use a <ul style="list-style-type: square;">, the zapfdingbats char 108 is used for the bullet point. This issue was reported on Stackoverflow and I will not rehash it here: [Embedding font using itext 5 for PDF/UA compliance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37577555/embedding-font-using-itext-5-for-pdf-ua-compliance)

As a workaround, I have used <ul style="list-style-image: url('images/arrowicon.png');"> which the PDF/UA validator (PAC 2 PDF Accessibility Checker 2) does not object to. There was an issue with scaling the image that I handled through a custom tag processor.

I have also found the same issue with the <ol style="list-style-type: upper-alpha;"> list where the font chosen for the symbol is Helvitca. I have tried to replace this using a custom tag processor.

Below is the custom tag processor I have used for both UL and OL list. The top part working with the image scaling works fine, it is the CSS.Value.UPPER_ALPHA where I cannot figure it out. This is the most simple example of what I have tried.

```
private class CustomUlTagProcessor : OrderedUnorderedList
    {
        public override IList<IElement> End(IWorkerContext ctx, Tag tag, IList<IElement> currentContent)
        {
            float fontSize = FontSizeTranslator.GetInstance().GetFontSize(tag);
            var elements = base.End(ctx, tag, currentContent);
            var imgScale = 9;

            var css = tag.CSS;
            CssUtils utils = CssUtils.GetInstance();

            foreach (var e in elements)
            {
                if (e is List)
                {
                    List list = (List)e;

                    string styleType;
                    css.TryGetValue(CSS.Property.LIST_STYLE_TYPE, out styleType);

                    if (css.ContainsKey(CSS.Property.LIST_STYLE_IMAGE)
                        && !Util.EqualsIgnoreCase(css[CSS.Property.LIST_STYLE_IMAGE], CSS.Value.NONE))
                    {
                        if (tag.Attributes.ContainsKey("data-image-size"))
                        {
                            int temp;
                            if (int.TryParse(tag.Attributes["data-image-size"], out temp))
                                imgScale = temp;
                        }


                        var url = utils.ExtractUrl(css[CSS.Property.LIST_STYLE_IMAGE]);

                        var img =
                            new ImageRetrieve(_context.ResourcePath, _context.GetImageProvider()).RetrieveImage(url);

                        img.Alt = "Checkbox";
                        //sizing the image to 12pt which is 9px
                        img.ScaleAbsolute(imgScale, imgScale);
                        //required to ensure the image is not scaled improperly.
                        img.ScaleToFitHeight = false;
                        img.Role = PdfName.ARTIFACT;

                        list.ListSymbol = new Chunk(img, 0, 0, false);
                        list.SymbolIndent = img.Width;

                    }

                    if (CSS.Value.UPPER_ALPHA.Equals(styleType) || CSS.Value.UPPER_LATIN.Equals(styleType))
                    {
                        //Set colour to red to see change easily
                        list.Symbol.Font = new Font(HeaderBaseFont, 12, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);

                    }

                }
            }
            return elements;
        }
    }
```

I have traced the problem with how the List is handling the fonts but I am at a loss of how to fix it in a custom tag processor which I believe is the easier solution. I have also considered doing my own List class to fix the issue.